# Create and write to a text file inmemory and convert to byte array in one go

Tags: c#, file, filestream, system.io.file

How can I create a .csv file implicitly/automatically by using the correct method, add text to that file existing in memory and then convert to in memory data to a byte array?

```
string path = @"C:\test.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(path, GetLines());
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

With that approach I create a file always (good), write into it (good) then close it (bad) then open the file again from a path and read it from the hard disc (bad)

How can I improve that?

UPDATE

One nearly good approach would be:

```
  using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {

                    fs.CopyTo(memoryStream );
                    return memoryStream .ToArray();
                }

        }
```

but I am not able to write text into that filestream... just bytes...

**UPDATE 2**

```
 using (var fs = File.Create(@"C:\temp\test.csv"))
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        String message = "Message is the correct ääüö Pi(\u03a0), and Sigma (\u03a3).";
                        sw.Write(message);
                        sw.Flush();
                        fs.CopyTo(ms);
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
```

**The string message is not persisted to the test.csv file. Anyone knows why?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Write text into Memory Stream.

```
byte[] bytes = null;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms)){
       tw.Write("blabla");
       tw.Flush();
       ms.Position = 0;
       bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
  
}
```

UPDATE

Use file stream Directly and write to File

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\ed\test.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        tw.Write("blabla");
        tw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you pass the TextWriter to the FileStream? Creating a FileStream you can not pass that.

Comment: TextWriter accept a stream as input so you can use FileStream directly on it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my original question. I do not just want to create a text file... please consider also the byte[] with the "text" data I want.

Comment: merge my answer with your first update,I think it will work

Comment: You have any idea why UPDATE 2 does not write anything into my file?

Comment: So you tested my code of UPDATE2 and it worked really?

Comment: Oh... I looked in the wrong DIRectory. Yes its written into that file, but the byte[] returned to the user in the browser which results in a file if download is EMPTY. That wonders me...

Comment: What is point of `ms.WriteTo(ms);` ?

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz Was a bad edit by admin (removed)

Answer (score 18):

You can get a byte array from a string using encoding:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aString);
```

Or

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aString);
```

But I don't know why you would want a csv as bytes. You could load the entire file to a string, add to it and then save it:

```
string content;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

content += "x,y,z";

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
    writer.Write(content);
}
```

Update: Create a csv in memory and pass back as bytes:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var line in GetLines())
{
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(line);
}
return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: I want a .csv file as bytes returning them from a HttpGet request as a file for the user.

Comment: Do you actually want a csv file to be created on disk, or just the bytes to pass back?

Comment: Return byte[] is enough - if thats possible -

Comment: Although ASCII has the chars 'ö', 'Ä' which are german. Still my excel or notepadd++ did display them as '?????' string. Is that a problem of those apps? When I use UTF8 it works.

Comment: If you're using those chars then utf8 is better. Ascii is not really suitable for that.