# C# - Create File then put it as a variable object

Tags: c#

Good day,

I'm trying to create a file programmatically using C# and that file will be attach or send to email.

I want to file contains a string just like below..

```
var stringInsideTheFile = new StringBuilder("Hello, I'm a test only");
```

I'm trying, `File` but requires a path. which is I don't need.

```
var test = File.WriteAllLines(path, content);
```

To summarize, I just want a help how to create a file programmatically and use that object with a content from string builder.

any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and write to a text file inmemory and convert to byte array in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661211/create-and-write-to-a-text-file-inmemory-and-convert-to-byte-array-in-one-go)

Comment: It seems like `MemoryStream` is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Something isn't a "file" until it's written to a file system, which involves a path.  How are you "attaching" the data to your email?  Is there perhaps an overload of one of those methods which accepts a `Stream`?

Comment: you can store the file on the server and then send that in the attachment

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store the file in the temp directory.

```
var stringInsideTheFile = "Hello, I'm a test only";
var filename = string.Format("%TEMP%\{0}", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
var test = File.WriteAllText(filename, stringInsideTheFile);
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(filename));
File.Delete(filename);
```

Comment: But I don't need to store the file in any directory sir